# Kalend create event console height Nan error

Tags: reactjs, calendar, frontend

I'm trying to use Kalend in a react project and after creating an event by dragging instead of just clicking I get this error:
[console error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vxET.png)

I'm pretty sure it's some problem in the library's component itself.

the library's github link is this: https://github.com/nibdo/kalend

Comment: post your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.